# Specified key was too long - max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: java, mysql, utf8mb4

When I executed the following command:

```
create table assessment (
    id integer not null auto_increment unique,
    assignment_weight_type tinyint not null,
    description varchar(255),
    end_date datetime not null,
    from_grade tinyint not null,
    f_id tinyint not null,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    start_date datetime not null,
    status tinyint not null,
    weight smallint,
    school_id integer not null,
    school_year_id integer not null,
    s_id integer, primary key (id),
    unique (name, school_id, school_year_id, from_grade, f_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I got this error message:

```
Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

I am using a charset of utf8mb4. So why did I get the error message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`utf8mb4` uses up to four bytes per character, so the name could occupy as much as 1020 bytes all by itself.

Comment: +1 beat me to it. If you want a field to be 255 bytes long, and not 255 characters, use a `varbinary` field.

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting same issue,i SET value for these variable in mysql as below and its fixed the issue.

1.global.innodb_large_prefix = 1

2.innodb_file_format=Barracuda

3.innodb_file_format_max=Barracuda

Answer (score -1):

Use this command to create the database.

```
 create database <DATABASE_NAME> character set latin1;
```

Comment: MySQL originally used the latin1 character set by default, which stored characters in a 2-byte sequence. If we use this, we can get more length to save the key length.

Comment: Yeah. But the OP asked about columns containing UTF8 characters. And I don't think that he want to skip that requirement **six years later**

Comment: I also faced this issue and I solved using this. So i thought it will be helpful for this also.

Comment: If you don't want to use UTF8, it's fine. But that does not match the asked use case