# MySQL INSERT if a identical entire row doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, insert, row, unique

I have a table with 10 columns and I have to add many, many rows from a CSV file. Of course, I must not add two identical rows, so I need a SQL statement that ignore the command if the entire row does exists. The INSERT must be ignored only if all fields are identical. Two rows may have identical *field1* or *field2*, but not all fields identical.

I tried `INSERT IGNORE` but it doesn't work. No column is set as `UNIQUE`, as the `INSERT` must be ignored onyl only if the entire row is identical.

What solution do you have for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a combined index on **all columns**, then `INSERT IGNORE` or `REPLACE INTO` according to your needs.

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing **UNIQUE index** or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued.

Comment: I added a INDEX to all columns the used INSERT IGNORE, it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, but two fields can have identical values. the INSERT is not permitted only if the entire row is already existing - each field of the new row is identical to each field of the existing one

Comment: If I set UNIQUE INDEX, I cannot have identical values in two rows.

Comment: Not a UNIQUE INDEX on **every single** column, but a combined UNIQUE INDEX on **all columns together**, this fits your requirements

Comment: Well, I get this when trying to apply INDEX to all at once: #1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Comment: If this is the case, you have run against a limit in keeping data unique in MySQL. You might want to check, if you really need these 1000 bytes - did you chose too long data types "just to make sure" ?

Comment: O.K. I limited the length of the value to be checked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes/1814594#1814594

Comment: @EugenRieck how do you think this would result in a table with 26 million rows ? the table has just 3 columns and one of them is primary id. the other columns are two values that i hold for relation. one of them is a varchar(30) and the other one is INT.Would it have a deep impact on regular insert ?