# Insert Unique Rows into Database Tables Using Java, Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, unique

I don't know this is already asked or not. But I don't find anyone. (Anyway this is not required for my project. But when I was working with database and Hibernate I had a doubt and now got time to ask here. So I have not tried so far about what I am going to ask here)

Suppose I have table in my database. I want to insert data into the table, but only Unique rows.

How it can be possible?

From, [this SO Qestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022407/mysql-insert-if-a-identical-entire-row-doesnt-exist), i think, we can insert unique rows into databse.

So in Java, Using `PreparedStatement` , can we be able to pass the same query so that it will insert rows only if that row is unique in the table?

If it is possible, what **ERROR/EXCEPTION, Java** will throw?

If not possible, what will be the best way to do so?

And also how about if we are using hibernate? How can we do the same?

If I am passing the **bean class object** to save the fields, how can I check for Unique rows?

Also how to perform the same with **List of Objects**?

Hope everyone Understood the situation.

Comment: It's much better to enforce uniqueness at database level not application level. This can be done via unique constraints. (I do realise this doesn't answer your question!)

Comment: @Muel that's a good idea. so when we try to insert a duplicate row it will throw an error I think
But when trying to save using hibernate and also with list of objects I dont know how to achieve

Comment: Do a google for "<your database> add unique constraint". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So in Java, Using PreparedStatement , can we be able to pass the same
>   query so that it will insert rows only if that row is unique in the
>   table?

If you have set unique constraints for your fields in your table, it will fail inserting duplicates.

> If it is possible, what ERROR/EXCEPTION, Java will throw?

Your database will raise an error; something like :

```
Duplicate entry 'xxxx' for key 'whatever'
```

Hopefully your java application will bring up that error from the database in a way or another...

> If I am passing the bean class object to save the fields, how can I
>   check for Unique rows?
>
> Also how to perform the same with List of Objects?

If you are manipulating beans then simply override `equals()` and use a `java.util.Set` instead of a `List` when inserting multiple rows.

Anyway, like @Muel said: "It's much better to enforce uniqueness at database level not application level." so as to never get corrupted data in your database.  However, it is also very easy to override `equals` in your beans and check if you don't have two (or more) objects which are identical.

Comment: If `equals()` is being overridden it's advisable that `hashCode()` is also overridden. Especially if using the common `HashSet`!

Comment: @Muel Yes you're right ! In fact I always override `equals()` and `hashcode()` together

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate works on object identifier (id), if object already have identifier then hibernate will try to update that object instead of insertion.

You can use simple solution like : get object on primary id from db , if object exist extract identifier and set identifier to new object it will be updated , if object does not exist it will be inserted and use "saveOrupdate"

From hibernate docs :

Hibernate users have requested a general purpose method that either saves a transient instance by generating a new identifier or updates/reattaches the detached instances associated with its current identifier

saveOrUpdate() does the following:

- if the object is already persistent in this session, do nothing
- if another object associated with the session has the same identifier, throw an exception
- if the object has no identifier property, save() it
- if the object's identifier has the value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it
- if the object is versioned by a  or , and the version property value is the same value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it otherwise update() the object