# not able to create table in mysql

Tags: mysql

when i try to create below table in my sql i got an error stating that

ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

```
CREATE TABLE fields_meta_data 
(id varchar(255)  NOT NULL ,
 name varchar(255)  NULL ,
 vname varchar(255)  NULL ,
 comments varchar(255)  NULL ,
 help varchar(255)  NULL ,
 custom_module varchar(255)  NULL ,
 type varchar(255)  NULL ,
 len int(11)  NULL ,
 required bool  DEFAULT '0' NULL ,
 default_value varchar(255)  NULL ,
 date_modified datetime  NULL ,
 deleted bool  DEFAULT '0' NULL ,
 audited bool  DEFAULT '0' NULL ,
 massupdate bool  DEFAULT '0' NULL ,
 duplicate_merge smallint  DEFAULT '0' NULL ,
 reportable bool  DEFAULT '1' NULL ,
 importable varchar(255)  NULL ,
 ext1 varchar(255)  NULL ,
 ext2 varchar(255)  NULL ,
 ext3 varchar(255)  NULL ,
 ext4 text  NULL  , 
 PRIMARY KEY (id),   
 KEY idx_meta_id_del (id, deleted),   
 KEY idx_meta_cm_del (custom_module, deleted)
 )
```

Comment: Please format the code block nicer

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1814532/237312

Comment: how to do that i mean how can i achieve that ?

Comment: Would it not be better to create three simple indexes, on `id`, `custom_module` and `deleted`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to use such wide fields? Even for `id` you have used `VARCHAR(255)`.

You are trying to create keys/indexes which are just too wide.

If you simply reduce your appetite and use reasonable field defintions, like integer for `id`, and other fields narrower than 255, you should get it working in no time.

Comment: thanks for your reply when i reduced the id lenght to 36,i successfully created that table,,thanks once again :)

Comment: Glad you got it working. You should reduce size of other columns as low as you are permitted to - this can never hurt for performance and db size on disk.

Answer (score 0):

I gues you are using UTF8 character set. Your ID column takes 255 * 4 bytes, that is 1020 bytes, which is too much for MyISAM tables.