# Schema setup fails using Sonar and MySQL 5.6 on windows

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

I have installed Sonar 3.4.1 and Mysql 5.6.10 on a Windows Machine.

I have created a mysql schema "sonar" and granted all permissions on it to a user "sonar". I have configured sonar to use this user. I did this following the instructions on [the codehaus sonar page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+Sonar#InstallingSonar-InstallingSonarServer).

When starting sonar it starts creating tables in the schema. At some point an error occurs stating that the "Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes" (full error message at the end).

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes) the index length is limited in mysql. Because this is documented I expect Sonar to not create indexes longer than the limit. Obviously it tries to do so.

Did I miss some important configuration or are the two versions of sonar and mysql incompatbile? What can I do to get it working with these versions?

Full error message:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/11 11:28:25 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/11 11:28:25 | ==  CreateProperties: migrating ===============================================
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/11 11:28:25 | -- create_table("properties")
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/11 11:28:25 |    -> 0.0320s
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/11 11:28:25 |    -> 0 rows
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/11 11:28:25 | -- add_index(:properties, :prop_key, {:name=>"properties_key"})
2013.02.11 11:28:25 ERROR jruby.rack  unable to create shared application instance
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes: CREATE  INDEX `properties_key` ON `properties` (`prop_key`)
    from D:/Programs/sonar-3.4.1/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:183:in `execute'
[stacktrace omitted]
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (StandardError) An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes: CREATE  INDEX `properties_key` ON `properties` (`prop_key`)
2013.02.11 11:28:25 ERROR jruby.rack  Error: application initialization failed
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes: CREATE  INDEX `properties_key` ON `properties` (`prop_key`)
    from D:/Programs/sonar-3.4.1/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:183:in `execute'
[stacktrace omitted]
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (StandardError) An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes: CREATE  INDEX `properties_key` ON `properties` (`prop_key`)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/11 11:28:25 | 2013-02-11 11:28:25.421:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9000
```

Comment: Tested it with MySQL 5.5.30 and it worked. According to SONAR docs any MySQL 5.x is supported. I have created a [JIRA Issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4137) and will keep this question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, some indexes are created with a length greater than the max limit. The issue is that MySQL 5.6 does not silently truncate indexes anymore. This behavior does not seem to be expected (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html and the bug http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68453).

All that to say that Sonar 3.5 fixes this issue by creating indexes with the correct length (see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4137).

Comment: Interesting, that the mysql bug got closed as "Not a Bug" eventhough the documentation mentions explicitly, that non unique indexes are truncated.

If you add to your answer, that sonar 3.4.1 and mysql 5.6 are incompatible and will not run together i can accept your answer.