# MySql error on Windows but not on Linux, specified key was too long

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, innodb

I have an app that uses MySql, and the app provides a web UI to configure the DB.

I installed MySql 5.1.70 on a Windows Sever 2008 r2 box. I also installed MySql 5.1.70 on a Linux (RHEL 6.4) box.

When I point my app to the Windows box for MySql, I get this error:

> Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

but when I point the app to the Linux box running MySql, I do not get the error. I have verified that the app wants to use innodb as the engine.

I am curious why I would get the error from one install, and not the other. Does the innodb engine work differently on Windows than on Linux?

Comment: By writing your error on google I found this as 1st [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Answer (score 0):

Check out a discussion of this issue at:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68453

Things to check out:
character encoding,
MySQL versions,
value of the variable innodb_large_prefix.