# MySQL Specified key was too long

Tags: mysql, key, varchar

I don't understand the error I'm getting. The only field longer than 767 is `password` but it's not an index or anything.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE users (
    ->         id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->         email VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    ->         password VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
    ->         date_added INTEGER,
    ->         PRIMARY KEY (id),
    ->         UNIQUE (email)
    -> );
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

Comment: It's not an index? And what does `UNIQUE(email)` do then?

Comment: Try changing `email VARCHAR(256)` to `email VARCHAR(255)`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes.  Is this an INNODB table?

Comment: @N.B.I'm saying that `password` is the only one longer than 767 but it's not an index.

Comment: @Mark: Cool! :-)  See [`@Krish R`'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20909000/206403) for an explanation as to why that worked :-D

Comment: @Mark: Which version of MySQL you are using. Because, I am not getting any error when executed this create statement. I am using mysql 5.5.34

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**VARCHAR(1024)**

MySQL stores VARCHAR values as a 1-byte or 2-byte length prefix plus data. The length prefix indicates the number of bytes in the value. A VARCHAR column uses one length byte if values require no more than 255 bytes, two length bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes.

Prior to MySQL 5.0.3, a VARCHAR column with a length specification greater than **255** is converted to the smallest TEXT type that can hold values of the given length. For example, VARCHAR(500) is converted to TEXT, and VARCHAR(200000) is converted to MEDIUMTEXT.

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html