# Create mysql index on first part of word

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add an index on `title`:

```
alter table title_google add index(title)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

How would I do something like:

```
alter table title_google add index(title[:100])
```

Or the equivalent to make this index work on the first part of the column?

Comment: Might be your solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE title_google ADD INDEX(title(100))
```