# Laravel migration: unique key is too long, even if specified

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, unique-key

I am trying to migrate a users table in Laravel. When I run my migration I get this error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length
>   is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique
>   users_email_uniq(`email`))

my migration is as follows:

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 32);
    $table->string('username', 32);
    $table->string('email', 320);
    $table->string('password', 64);
    $table->string('role', 32);
    $table->string('confirmation_code');
    $table->boolean('confirmed')->default(true);
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->unique('email', 'users_email_uniq');
});
```

After some googling I came across [this bug report](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1710) where Taylor says you can specify the index key as the 2nd parameter of `unique()`, which I have done. It still gives the error. What is going on here?

Comment: Why are you using 320 chars for e-mail? This might be your problem.

Comment: That was indeed the problem, no idea why. But yes, you are right, I don't know why I specified the char length for each field. Have removed these limits

Comment: It's funny how no one suggested using fixed-length field that contains hash of the email and voila - problem solved forever, for any framework and for any relational database. Because that's how we guarantee uniqueness - using a fixed-number representation of variable-length input, given the fact that number range is sufficiently large (and for sha1 / sha256 it is).

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error may get help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Comment: removing ->unique() worked for me !

Answer (score 311, accepted):

Specify a smaller length for your e-mail:

```
$table->string('email', 250);
```

Which is the default, actually:

```
$table->string('email');
```

And you should be good.

For Laravel 5.4 you can find a solution in this [Laravel 5.4: Specified key was too long error, Laravel News](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error) post:

*As outlined in the Migrations guide to fix this all you have to do is edit your AppServiceProvider.php file and inside the boot method set a default string length:*

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder;


public function boot()
{
    Builder::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: Maximum possible email length is `254` so probably worth keeping this in mind, so I would probably validate the uniqueness using validator in that case.

Comment: I think scored aproach its safer, as it does really implements the charset in the database instead of doing tricks, you will probably find problems with emoticons.

Comment: For _Laravel 5.4_, use `\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder::defaultStringLength(191);` for correct function reference path

Comment: After making the configuration in the AppServiceProvider.php, this problem is still happening. I am just confused. Why?
I restarted server, database and everything but still. Please help.

Comment: You have to set the length of the indexed column according to the limit of 767 bytes. Be aware that VARCHAR may have 1, 2 or 4 bytes for each length unit. Example: utf8_mb4 (4 bytes) -> 767 / 4 = 191. Otherwise utf8_general_ci for VARCHAR(X) with X < 85 ( 1 byte ) = O(85) , or utf8_general_ci for VARCHAR(X) with X >= 86 ( 2 bytes ) -> 767 / 2 = 383. Consider also other columns lenght in multiple column indexes.

Comment: You may also want to edit directly the length of the specific column in the migration files, over specifying a default length for all the string columns, as not all columns will need this constraint as they aren't in any index. 
$table->string('column_name',191);

Comment: This fix is still working in 2019 for laravel version 5.8.*  (and mysql 5.6.* in my case) .Adding the default String length inside the boot() method fixes the 'key too long' error.

Comment: I have seen 191 characters in the official news letter too. https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error, but how did the 191 number calculated ?

Answer (score 119):

**Update 1**

As of [Laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/master/releases#laravel-5.4) those changes are no more needed.

> Laravel 5.4 uses the utf8mb4 character set by default, which includes support for storing "emojis" in the database. If you are upgrading your application from Laravel 5.3, you are not required to switch to this character set.

**Update 2**

Current production MariaDB versions **DO NOT** support this setting by default globally. It is implemented in [MariaDB 10.2.2+ by default](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/xtradbinnodb-storage-formats/#dynamic).

**Solution**

And if you intentionally want to use the correct future-default (starting from Laravel 5.4) UTF8 multi-byte `utf8mb4` support for  then start to fix  your database configuration.

In Laravel `config/database.php` define:

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',
```

`DYNAMIC` allows to store [long key](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/xtradbinnodb-server-system-variables/#innodb_large_prefix) indexes.

Server settings (by default included in MySQL 5.7.7+ / MariaDB 10.2.2+):

```
[mysqld]
# default character set and collation
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8mb4

# utf8mb4 long key index
innodb_large_prefix = 1
innodb_file_format = barracuda
innodb_file_format_max = barracuda
innodb_file_per_table = 1
```

For clients:

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

And then **STOP** your MySQL/MariaDB server. After that START. Hot RESTART may not work.

```
sudo systemctl stop mysqld
sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

Now you have Laravel 5.x with UTF8 support.

Comment: This might wok well enough with MySQL 5.5 (did not try to reconfigure). The 5.7 (probably also 5.6) worked without the need for any reconfiguration. The 5.7 was a default Community Server distribution with vanilla configuration.

Comment: I changed the engine in my database.php as you mentionned but it is still creating tables with row=compact which is causing a problem.

I didn't fully understand, are you saying that it isn't enough to make this change in database.php and that it is also required to make the changes in the my.cnf file ?

Comment: It is enough to make changes just in `database.php` config file and it will impact local Laravel project. Be sure to `delete` database before making changes and create it with new settings. You need to change `my.cnf`config file only for global server side changes (currently all new installations use `utf8mb4`).

Comment: Or - add another field, calculate the hash of the email, make the field unique, solve the problem forever, avoid fiddling with database initialization variables.

Comment: If anybody is **using Doctrine 2**, you can set ROW_FORMAT by passing `options={"row_format"="DYNAMIC"}` to your `@Table` annotation.

Comment: Thanks, you are king, this worked, but was important to set the engine in laravel, now we have 'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',

Comment: Just adding a bit `default-storage-engine=InnoDB` in my.ini along with this answer saved my day.

Comment: 'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC', line worked for me.

Comment: This fixed it with MySQL 8. Thank you!

Answer (score 61):

If you're on or updated to Laravel 5.4 This worked for me;

Just 1 change. in AppServiceProvider.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
  Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

As mentioned in the migrate guide https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-indexes

Comment: I did this on the migration itself.

Comment: This is (presumably) because each character takes up exactly 4 bytes, and the maximum key length is measured in bytes, not characters. So the key length will by 191 * 4 = 764 bytes, just a smidgen under the maximum 767 bytes the database will support. Solutions need explanations IMO if they are to contribute to the shared knowledge here, and not just provide "procedures". But a handy fix nonetheless.

Comment: this solution always work. But Why even laravel 10 this issue still exist?

Answer (score 35):

If anyone else stumbles upon this answer like I did but for a different reason, you may check your Laravel DB charset/collation.

I was installing an application (Snipe-IT) and had configured the Laravel database config to use the following:

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
```

Removing `mb4` from both strings fixed the issue, although I believe Antonio's answer is the real solution to the problem.

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me:

```
 $table->charset = 'utf8';
 $table->collation = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
```

Comment: This worked for me. I use Server version: 10.1.22-MariaDB - Source distribution

Answer (score 16):

For laravel 5.4, simply edit file

> App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: This also worked on laravel 8.1

Answer (score 16):

Remove `mb4` from charset and collation from `config/database.php`, then it will execute successfully.

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

Answer (score 14):

I have faced the same issue, and fixed it by adding the below two lines in my app/database.php

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

My file looks like below :

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',

    ......
```

Comment: If you installed new version in Laravel. Please remove 'mb4' from utf8mb4 & utf8mb4_unicode_ci & config/database.php

Answer (score 9):

i had same problem and i am using a wamp

Solution : 
Open file :
config/database.php

```
'engine' => null, => 'engine' => 'InnoDB',
```

Thanks

Comment: None of the previous answers worked for me, but this one worked like a charm! And it makes perfect sense, I believe in previous versions of Laravel DB engine was set to InnoDB by default so we didn't encounter these errors previously.

Comment: yes needed to do a couple of the other answers and this as well.

Answer (score 6):

For **Laravel >= 5.6** users

Open `AppServiceProvider.php` file

Use the following class

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

Then inside `boot` method add the following line

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I added to the migration itself

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

yes, I know I need to consider it on every migration but I would rather that than have it tucked away in some completely unrelated service provider

Answer (score 5):

If someone having this problem even after doing, above mentioned changes. For an example, in my case I did below changes,

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  /**
   * Register any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function register()
   {
      //
   }

   public function boot()
   {
     Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
   }
}
```

But it wouldn't work right away for two reasons. One is if you are using lumen instead of laravel, you may have to uncomment this line in your app.php file first.

```
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
```

And then you have to create the migration script again with the artisan command,

```
php artisan make:migration <your_table_name>
```

Since now only the changes you made to ServiceProvider will work.

Answer (score 4):

for laravel 5.7 write these code in appserviceprovider.php

```
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
  Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can go to `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` and import this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
```

also in boot function add this

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

Comment: Does not help my case.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel uses the `utf8mb4` character set by default, which includes support for storing "emojis" in the database. If you are running a version of MySQL older than the 5.7.7 release or MariaDB older than the 10.2.2 release, you may need to manually configure the default string length generated by migrations in order for MySQL to create indexes for them. You may configure this by calling the  `Schema::defaultStringLength` method within your `AppServiceProvider`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

You can check out of

https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#indexes

Comment: thanks, works for me. mamp mysql with laravel 5.6.23

Answer (score 2):

It's because **Laravel 5.4** uses **utf8mb4** which supports storing emojis.

Add this in your **app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on or updated to Laravel 5.4 and latest version it works;
Just 1 change in AppServiceProvider.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
  Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In 24 october 2016 **Taylor Otwell** the Author of Laravel  announced on is Twitter

> "utf8mb4" will be the default MySQL character set in Laravel 5.4 for better emoji support.  [Taylor Otwell Twitter Post](https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/790661501904261120?lang=fr)

which before version 5.4 the character set was `utf8`

During this century many web app, include chat or some kind platform to allow their users to converses, and many people like to use emoji or smiley. and this are some kind of super characters that require more spaces to be store and that is only possible using `utf8mb4` as the *charset*. That is the reason why they migrate to `utf8mb4` just for space purpose.

if you look up in the `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder` class you will see that the [`$defaultStringLength`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Schema/Builder.php#L37) is set to **255**, and to modify that you can procede through the `Schema` Facade and call the [`defaultStringLength`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Schema/Builder.php#L57) method and pass the new length.

to perform that change call that method within your `AppServiceProvider` class which is under the app\providers subdirectory like this

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // all other code ...

        Schema::defaultStringLength(191); 
    }
    // and all other code goes here
}
```

I will suggest to use **191** as the value just because MySQL support 767 bytes, and because `767 / 4` which is the number of byte take by each multibyte character you will get `191`.

You can learn more here 
[The utf8mb4 Character Set (4-Byte UTF-8 Unicode Encoding)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)
    [Limits on Table Column Count and Row Size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html)

Comment: This is the only answer that explains the `191` magic number.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point that something that i missed ...

I'm new at Laravel, and i didn't copy the "use Illuminate....." because i really didn'at paid atention, because right above the function boot you alread have a **use** Statement.

Hope that helps anyone

```
**use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;**

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: You can also just prefix any Facade with `\ `

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem, change the configuration of the 'config / database'

```
file 'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

keeping the same pattern in the database.

I then gave the command

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

First change the defaultStringLength to 191, in the *app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php*:

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Then, change the [charset and collation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/character-set-and-collation-overview/) values as follows, in *config\database.php*:

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

([link to know about MariaDB charset](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/unicode/))

Answer (score 0):

You will not have this problem if you're using MySQL 5.7.7+ or MariaDB 10.2.2+.

To update MariaDB on your Mac using Brew first unlink the current one:
`brew unlink mariadb` and then install a dev one using `brew install mariadb --devel`

After installation is done stop/start the service running:
`brew services stop mariadb
brew services start mariadb`

Current dev version is 10.2.3. After the installation is finished you won't have to worry about this anymore and you can use utf8mb4 (that is now a default in Laravel 5.4) without switching back to utf8 nor editing AppServiceProvider as proposed in the Laravel documentation:  https://laravel.com/docs/master/releases#laravel-5.4 (scroll down to: **Migration Default String Length**)

Answer (score 0):

Just installed MariaDB 10.2.4 RC, fired up new blank Laravel 5.4 project and default migration (varchar(255) columns) works.

No need to change DB conf and Laravael `config/database.php`. Thus just as @scorer noted about default behaviour for 10.2.2+.

Answer (score 0):

All was well described in the others Anwser
you can see more details in the link bellow (search with key 'Index Lengths & MySQL / MariaDB")
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations

**BUT WELL THAT's not what this answer is about!** the thing is even with doing the above **you will like get another error** (that's when you like launch `php artisan migrate` command and because of the problem of the length, the operation like stuck in the middle. **solution is bellow**, and the user table is like created without the rest or not totally correctly)
**we need to roll bac**k. the default roll back will not do. because the operation of migration didn't like finish. you need to delete the new created tables in the database manually.

**we can do it using tinker as in bellow:**

```
L:\todos> php artisan tinker

Psy Shell v0.8.15 (PHP 7.1.10 — cli) by Justin Hileman

>>> Schema::drop('users')

=> null
```

I myself had a problem with users table.

after that your good to go

```
php artisan migrate:rollback

php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Set database engine InnoDB:

```
  Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried every other answer and they have not worked, you can drop all tables from the database and then execute the migrate command all at once using this command:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing this error then definitely you need to make following changes on 
`AppServiceProvider.php` file -> which can be found inside `app->providers:`

changes to be made

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; //see if you have this class if not add it.

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191); //make sure you add this line
}
```

this should solve your problem for more you can see the Laravel news regarding this issue. 
https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Answer (score 0):

Give a smaller length for your email string like :

```
$table->string('email',128)->unique(); //In create user table
```

And

```
$table->string('email',128)->index(); // create password resets table
```

This will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a smaller length for your e-mail:

```
$table->string('email', 100);
```

100 WORKS

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that those articles goes with the easy and wrong solution. It's like chopping of part of your foot because your socks doesn't fit.

The correct answer (to buy a new sock) is a bit more complex since it requires you to go to the store again. In this case it requires you to configure your mysql instance, and that isn't as copy/pastable as a wrong answer, so we keep propagating the wrong answer. We want to seem copy/pastable and easy to use, right?

You forgot to specify which Laravel or mysql version you are using. The problem occurs because you are using an older mysql (or newer with wrong settings).

```
Set innodb_file_format=Barracuda
Set innodb_large_prefix=1
Set innodb_default_row_format=dynamic
```

If you do not have the innodb_default_row_format setting (introduced in 5.7.9), then you have to change your config/database.php to use 'engine' => 'innodb row_format=dynamic'.

The engine setting was introduced in Laravel 5.2.14, so I hope you have something newer than that.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22660#issuecomment-355725923

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it can help if you agree to unique only **the first 191 сhars**

```
public function up()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `YOUR_TABLE_NAME`    ADD UNIQUE INDEX `NAME_FOR_INDEX` (`YOUR_COLUMN_NAME` (191) );');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same error pops up because of the way Laravel unique() function works.

The only thing you need to do is specify a shorter index name eg.

```
$table->unique(['email', 'users_email_uniq'],'my_custom_uniq');
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php , add this code in public function

boot():

```
{
    //
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

};`
```

and use this :`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`

Answer (score -1):

include this line at top

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

then inside boot function add this

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLenght(191);
}
```

Comment: Could you please format your code by highlighting it and hitting Ctrl+K

Answer (score -1):

Please open `user` and `password` rest files. files are located in database/migrations folder.

add line

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191); in up function in both files.
```

Then run

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: You would have to this for ANY model that uses the String datatype, so this is not optimal. The other answers deal with it once for ALL migrations. The "real/best" solution depends on your environment and needs. If you MUST use an older MySQL (or Maria) but want to keep the 250 string length and do not need emojis, then switch the DB charset. Otherwise shorten the max string length in the provider.