# Why is MySQL ignoring the data type length for a column?

Tags: mysql, url, varchar

I am using MySQL 8.0 and I am trying to store a URL in a column. Every time I try to insert a URL longer than 191 characters, I get the following error:

```
1406 Data too long for column 'url' at row 1
```

The column data type is VARCHAR(1000) and the URL is ~450 characters. I have tried inserting other strings and anything 191 characters and under works fine but nothing does over 191 chars.

I have tried changing the datatype for this column to other string formats like TEXT, LONGTEXT, and BLOB. I have also tried inserting strings over 191 characters in other tables and they are also limited to 191 characters.

I know utf8mb4 causes VARCHAR(255) to actually be 191 but I shouldn't it be possible to override that with VARCHAR(1000)? Is there a setting in the database that can cause this issue?

Comment: Use `TEXT` instead of `VARCHAR` if you want more than 191 characters

Comment: I did try using TEXT already. It is also limited to 191 characters.

Comment: Do you have a trigger that is copying the value to another table?

Comment: FYI, MySQL 8.0 defaults to an InnoDB configuration that allows longer indexes up to 3072 bytes, so there's no longer a need to limit yourself to VARCHAR(191) to fit string indexes in the 768 byte limit of earlier versions.

Comment: Yes, there is a trigger adding this data to another table.

Comment: What is the column size of the `url` column in the other table?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://community.modx.com/t/why-do-some-fields-have-a-varchar-precision-of-191-for-moduserprofile-in-the-modx-schema/940):

```
On a database that uses a utf8mb collation, each character takes 4 bytes.
On innodb, indexes (the prefixes to be exact) can contain up to 767 bytes.

So, the max indexable length on utf8mb + innodb is 767/4=191 characters.
```

So you better to use `TEXT` format for your URLs.

UPDATED:

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43833633/973254), the problem is in charset, which is `utf8mb4` when it needs to be `utf8`, same for collation.

Comment: I tried using TEXT already and it is still limited to 191 chars.

Comment: @Rahbui same for `TEXT`, you need to change `utf8mb4` to `utf8`, same for collation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43833633/973254