# sql error when seeding Specified key was too long for email

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I just started a new project in laravel so it's the latest version 5.4, I'm getting an error when seeding to the database for a single user and I'm getting this error

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was t
  oo long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique
  `users_email_unique`(`email`))

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was t
  oo long; max key length is 1000 bytes

```
User::create([
    'name' => 'someone'
    'email' => 'someone@outlook.com',
    'password' => bcrypt('mypassword'), 
]);


<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel migration: unique key is too long, even if specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786359/laravel-migration-unique-key-is-too-long-even-if-specified)

Comment: Your question appears to be a close duplicate of the link above.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this like:

```
use  Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; // At the top of your file
```

And add this line in the boot() method of the AppServiceProvider :

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```