# domain.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: laravel-5.5

Good day guy, please i am having issues with my laravel5.5 site online. with this error
domain.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500.

I will appreciate any help or suggestion.
Thanks
Kel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel migration: unique key is too long, even if specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786359/laravel-migration-unique-key-is-too-long-even-if-specified)

Answer (score -1):

This comes up if you are using Laravel 5.4+ (default database character set changed to *utf8mb4*) with mySQL version under MySQL v5.7.7.

Edit your `AppServiceProvider.php` file and inside the boot method set a default string length:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

After that everything should work as normal.

From: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Comment: Thanks Though, Still same error online after upload : currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500.

Comment: Thanks, I Simply Used An Older version and a way round the problem.