# php artisan migrate : error

Tags: php, laravel

```
$ php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.
In Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users`
add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))
In Connection.php line 449:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

what's the problem?:|

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel migration: unique key is too long, even if specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786359/laravel-migration-unique-key-is-too-long-even-if-specified)

Comment: `what's the problem?:|`

Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```