# laravel default username & password migration error

Tags: php, laravel

In Connection.php line 647:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was
>      too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add uni
>     que `users_email_unique`(`email`))

In Connection.php line 449:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was
>      too long; max key length is 1000 bytes. . . .

How can i solve this??

When i want to migrate default migrations in CMD this error happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel migration: unique key is too long, even if specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786359/laravel-migration-unique-key-is-too-long-even-if-specified)

Comment: Set a shorter key length? You've set your email field to a really long value? Can you post the table structure?

Comment: well this is because mySQL indexes are only available for string that has length lower than 192 .. you may want to change the defaultStringLength ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your `AppServiceProvider.php` file:

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

This [article](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error) by `Laravel News` explains it

Answer (score 2):

For Laravel 5.4 add code in AppServiceProvider.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

and in `boot`

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```