# Artisan 'Nothing to rollback' when there is a table already created

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I wanted to make a migration using `php artisan migrate` but I got an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

So naturally I wanted to drop my tables using `php artisan migrate:rollback`, but I got:

> Nothing to rollback.

What the heck? It said just earlier that the `users` table was already created. What should I do? I can delete the table with phpmyadmin but I want to learn how to use artisan.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What if you use `php artisan migrate:reset` instead?

Comment: You can only rollback the last migration executed. Is there any last migration that can be rolled back? What is the output of `php artisan migrate:status`? Do you see any migrations in the `migrations` table from the database? If so, are those migrations what are you expecting them to be?

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow was on maintenance for a couple of minutes and I tried to manage it myself. What I did is delete all the tables (even the migration one) using phpmyadmin, and then I fixed what caused the fact that I had to make a `php artisan migrate:rollback` in the first place, I added `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` in AppServiceProvider. Now it seems to work well.

Comment: Write the solution as an answer.

Comment: @Troyer That's done.

Answer (score 3):

Failing an answer to *how to delete the tables with artisan when there is this problem*, I will tell you how to avoid this problem in the first place. Ultimately I just deleted the tables using phpmyadmin.

I watched a tutorial on Laravel and I saw that in order to avoid the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

I had to add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` in `AppServiceProvider.php` and `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` in the `boot()` function. But I thought that I could put any number in `defaultStringLength(...)` so I put 255, and the migration didn't work.

Do as it is told in the tutorials, write `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);`. Then, you can execute your migration using `php artisan migrate` and it should work properly.

Answer (score 2):

In my case after defining `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` in the `boot()` method didn't solved. Because the `migrations` table in the database is empty.
So the solution is open up the tinker from the composer

```
$ php artisan tinker
>>> Schema::drop('users')
>>> Schema::drop('password_resets')
>>> Schema::drop('orders')
>>> exit
php artisan migrate
```

Here is the result of the above commands executed

```
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$ php artisan migrate
```

> In Connection.php line 647:
>                                                                                     SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users'
>   already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not
>   null auto_incr     ement primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null,
>   `email` varchar(255) not n     ull, `password` varchar(255) not null,
>   `remember_token` varchar(100) null,      `created_at` timestamp null,
>   `updated_at` timestamp null) default character      set utf8mb4
>   collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
>
> In Connection.php line 449:
>                                                                                     SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users'
>   alre     ady exists

```
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$ php artisan migrate:rollback
Nothing to rollback.
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.8.17 (PHP 7.1.20-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> Schema::drop('users')
=> null
>>> Schema::drop('password_resets')
=> null
>>> Schema::drop('orders')
=> null
>>> exit
Exit:  Goodbye.
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$ php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrating: 2018_08_18_071213_create_orders_table
Migrated:  2018_08_18_071213_create_orders_table
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$
```

Also define the method `down()`, if it doesn't exist. 
Otherwise, it'll show

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'XYZ.ABC' (SQL: drop table `ABC`)

```
/**
  * Reverse the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
  */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('ABC');
}
```

Comment: Beware, Tkinter and Tinker are not the same thing XD
But you're right though, it was because my `migrations` table was empty.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION:**

```
>> php artisan migrate:fresh
```

It will drop all tables and recreates all the migrations.

Comment: Your answer is good if we just want to delete the tables, but we must also correct the problem of the table that is created by Artisan but that does not appear in the migration table when we use `defaultStringLength(255)`. I don't know if it's a bug of Artisan but that's the core problem.

Comment: I am not sure if you are concerned about this issue too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54265587/5276297

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan db:wipe`

It is a quick way to drop all the tables, their types and views if you’re using Laravel 6.x

Full description:

`$ php artisan db:wipe {--database=} {--drop-views} {--drop-types} {--force}`

- `database` - The database connection to use
- `drop-views` - Drop all tables and views
- `drop-types` - Drop all tables and types (Postgres    only)
- `force` - Force the operation to run when in production

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` in AppServiceProvider.php and `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` in the `boot()` function
2. Run `php artisan migrate:fresh`
3. Run `php artisan migrate` again

Solved!