# Laravel's Eloquent: bypass the 191 characters VARCHAR limitation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, varchar

As indicated by [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786359/laravel-migration-unique-key-is-too-long-even-if-specified), [this person](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error) and [this person](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-54-failing-on-php-artisan-migrate-after-php-artisan-makeauth?page=1), in order to avoid a

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

you have to modify the `AppServiceProvider.php` of your Laravel project like that:

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;              //add this

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot() {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);           //and this
    }

    public function register() { }
}
```

But the drawback of this method is that the VARCHARs I use are limited to 191 characters, and I want to have a field longer than that. How should I do?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The questions you link to has several answers about how you can configure your mysql server to support this thing (indexes longer than 191 characters). What's wrong with those?

Comment: Because I will deploy my project onto my client's machine and I don't know which MySQL version will be supported. Besides, I didn't know that setting the VARCHAR's length in the migration allowed to bypass the 255 characters limitation.

Comment: Setting the varchar's length in the migration _does not_ get rid of the limitation. The limitation comes from trying to create an index on a table and the index becomes longer than supported. There will be no limitation if you never create an index on the varchar field. However, Laravel creates an index on the users.email field in the default migration, thus people see this limit in their new project. I think you should just document the mysql configuration as a application requirement, and let their technical team solve it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually on your migration file you can define the size. Example

```
$table->string('field_name', 200);
```

Comment: How far can I go? If the limit is 250, I don't think that will be enough either.

Comment: 255 is the maximum, but the only real way to solve this is by upgrading your mysql version.

Comment: If you want longer size, use `text` type instead. Varchar limitation is maximum 255 character length

Comment: Apparently it worked perfectly. I created a field with more than 1000 characters.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi how long is the text you are inserting into this field? does it exceed 255, the normal varchar length without the appserviceprovider code? if not it would be a 'huge' performance waste to use a text field for this purpose

Comment: @Quezler No, I mean that I used VARCHAR and not TEXT. It surprises me as much as you but you can give a greater value than 255 in the `$table->string('field',1000);`.

Comment: that is a surprise indeed

Comment: Seriously? Just knowing that we can set size more than 255. What a surprise.

Comment: Ahh. There is the explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506832/what-is-the-mysql-varchar-max-size, we can set the size at maximum  `65,535`.

Answer (score 1):

[You will have to upgrade your MySQL version to `v5.7.7` or higher.](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error)