# Laravel migrate - column type string doesn't update size

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations

I created a migration to update the size of a VARCHAR column in MySQL and to rename it in the same migration. So to change a VARCHAR() type through Laravel Schema we use **string()** base on [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations)

This is the function up():

```
Schema::table('address', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('place_id', 100)->change();
    $table->renameColumn('place_id', 'full_address');
});
```

and the function down():

```
Schema::table('address', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('full_address', 255)->change();
    $table->renameColumn('full_address', 'place_id');
});
```

It is renaming the column but it is not changing the size, any ideas why?.

MySQL table

```
Field, table, Type, Character Set, Display Size
place_id,address,VARCHAR,utf8,255
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "it's not working"

Comment: What's the `php artisan ...` command you're running?

Comment: I updated the question. I am running `php artisan migrate`, and `migrate:rollback`. I dunno if it's possible to change the size and rename the column in the same migration.

Comment: What does the table look like after you run `migrate` and before you run `migrate:rollback`?

Comment: After running `migrate => full_address VARCHAR 255`, then after running `rollback  => full_address VARCHAR 255`. It renames it but doesn't change the size

Comment: This was helpful for me: `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23786522/470749 and https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I am not sure if it's the best one, but it is better to use **multiple Schemas**.

```
Schema::table('address', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->string('place_id', 100)->change();
});

Schema::table('address', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->renameColumn('place_id', 'full_address');
});
```