# LUMEN : How to fix the SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 on laravel lumen

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb, lumen

I started a PHP project with the lumen framework.

When I try to execute the command `php artisan migrate:fresh` from the console I get the following error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071

It is a well known error in Laravel but this question is not a duplicate because there is no boot method on lumen, as the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#indexes) says :

> Laravel uses the utf8mb4 character set by default, which includes support for storing "emojis" in the database. If you are running a version of MySQL older than the 5.7.7 release or MariaDB older than the 10.2.2 release, you may need to manually configure the default string length generated by migrations in order for MySQL to create indexes for them. You may configure this by calling the Schema::defaultStringLength method within your AppServiceProvider.

However, when I try to use this fix in the microframework Lumen the error is still there.

Comment: What version of **MySQL** / **MariaDB** are you using? Can you show us your attempt and where you did it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel migration: unique key is too long, even if specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786359/laravel-migration-unique-key-is-too-long-even-if-specified)

Answer (score 1):

This error basically comes from you have not set `defaultStringLength` in `boot()` function

> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071

**SOLUTION:**

Just Add the below code in **app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php** method:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: Only my opinion: I don't like this solution since it reduce the `string` column from 255 to 191 characters. When I used to had the same error (I guess we all did :)) I chose [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39750202/8068675) I didn't needed to change `max:255` to `max:191` on all the validations and back when I upgraded MariaDB.  And this answer actually solve the problem, instead of providing a fix.

Comment: The boot method must be inside the class ? @UdhavSarvaiya

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php check here

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya Yes it's what I did, but no it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: @cbaconnier The problem is that there is no config/database.php in lumen

Answer (score 1):

In Lumen you have also to uncomment the line:

`$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);` In **bootstrap/app.php**