# Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel and when I try to run `php artisan make:migrate` it shows this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))
>
> at /Users/soksan/Desktop/TestLaravel/multiUsers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664

```
  660|    // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
  661|    // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
  662|    // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
  663|    catch (Exception $e) {
> 664|        throw new QueryException(
  665|            $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
  666|        );
  667|    }
  668|
```

Exception trace:

> 1   `PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes")`
>        /Users/soksan/Desktop/TestLaravel/multiUsers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458
>
> 2   `PDOStatement::execute()`
>        /Users/soksan/Desktop/TestLaravel/multiUsers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458

Please use the argument `-v` to see more details.

Comment: can you show us your migration code?

Comment: please add the user migration code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel migration: unique key is too long, even if specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786359/laravel-migration-unique-key-is-too-long-even-if-specified)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29676724/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go in the `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` class and change the boot method to look like this

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It's worked for me.

Comment: added with namespace: `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::defaultStringLength(191);`

Comment: Instead of specifying the Full Qualified Name of the `Schama` class you could add  ` use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` on top of your PHP file

Answer (score 4):

Go to your laravel project and inside that project open `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` class and change the boot method and add new schema show in the image.

Add this line at the top

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`

Replace this method

`public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }`

[image: Go to AppServiceProvider.php]

Answer (score 1):

Find the file config/database.php and change the charset and collation from utf8mb4 to utf8

'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',