# My SQL Script erro 1071 - Does Not Work ADD UNIQUE or Change ENGINE

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1071

```
  `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Odin`.`Usuario` (
  `CodUsuario` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CodTipoUsuario` INT NOT NULL,
  `CodConsultorTecnico` INT NULL,
  `CodProdutor` INT NULL,
  `Login` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NOT NULL,
  `Senha` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NOT NULL,
  `Ativo` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `MaiorDataRegistrada` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `DataLimite` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '01/01/2014',
  `MaxFazendas` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `MaxFemeas` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `CodUserWeb` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `CodEstudante` INT NULL,
  `UltimoBackup` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CodUsuario`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `UQ__Usuario__00000000000006D8` (`Login` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Usu_ref_Est`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CodEstudante`)
    REFERENCES `Odin`.`Estudante` (`CodEstudante`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Fk_Usuario_Ref_Consultor`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CodConsultorTecnico`)
    REFERENCES `Odin`.`ConsultorTecnico` (`CodConsultorTecnico`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Fk_Usuario_Ref_Produtor`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CodProdutor`)
    REFERENCES `Odin`.`Produtor` (`CodProdutor`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Fk_Usuario_Ref_TipoUsuario`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CodTipoUsuario`)
    REFERENCES `Odin`.`ConfTipoUsuario` (`CodTipoUsuario`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION) `
```

I've tried solutions such as:
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
or
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

or ADD UNIQUE

and still continue with the error:

## 1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Comment: I saw this solution, but could not make it work, anyway thanks for trying

Answer (score 1):

You are using `utf8mb4` which is 1-4 bytes per character.

You chose `VARCHAR(255)` - 255 characters * 4 bytes = 1020.

Try with less characters. Like `VARCHAR(191)`.

Also have a look into `innodb_large_prefix`.