# Hibernate cannot create table hibernate_sequences

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mariadb

Hibernate version:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

`ExportDB.java`:

```
public class ExportDB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry).buildMetadata();
        SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport();
        schemaExport.create(EnumSet.of(TargetType.DATABASE), metadata);
    }
}
```

Run `ExportDB.java`:

```
2016-11-19 00:22:12,845 WARN [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] - HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Hibernate: drop table if exists hibernate_sequences
Hibernate: drop table if exists user
Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequences (sequence_name varchar(255) not null, sequence_next_hi_value bigint, primary key (sequence_name))
Hibernate: create table user (id bigint not null, balance decimal(20,4) default 0.00, createTime time, displayName varchar(64), password varchar(64), username varchar(64), primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table user add constraint UK_7kuje5s4lbyq9qyv1r9ecm2it unique (username)
```

Database:

```
MariaDB [cms]> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_cms |
+----------------+
| investor       |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I use printed SQL to create `hibernate_sequences`:

```
MariaDB [cms]> create table hibernate_sequences (sequence_name varchar(255) not null, next_val bigint, primary key (sequence_name));
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

How can I make `ExportDB.java` can create `hibernate_sequences`?

Comment: It appears that your variable `sequence_name` is too large to use as a primary key.  Take a look at this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes   255 characters at 3 bytes per character is 765 bytes, plus a few extra bytes are required, so it goes over the 767 limit.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `utf8mb4`, correct?  And you are using 5.6 or older?

Plan A:  Upgrade to 5.7.

Plan B:  Decrease 255 to 191 or less.  (Did you really need 255??)

Plan C:  Change to `CHARACTER SET utf8` (assuming you don't need Emoji or Chinese)

Plan D:  Normally a 'sequence' is something numeric.  If that is the case, won't `INT UNSIGNED` or `BIGINT UNSIGNED` work?

Comment: Thank you, but how to change to utf8? You mean the whole database?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO ...` for any table needing to change.  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the `utf8mb4` charset **on the column definition** in my case.

Too long varchar column cannot be used in primary_key.

So we can manually create the table and make it correct.

The following create table query do the trick.

```
create table hibernate_sequences (
   sequence_name varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 not null ,
    next_val bigint,
    primary key (sequence_name)
) engine=MyISAM
```