# Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes. SQL Error: 1071

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dbo`.`Discounts` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Description` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL,
  `Code` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL,
  `Catalog_Id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `UQ_Discounts_CatalogCode` (`Catalog_Id` ASC, `Code`(255) ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `Discount_Catalog`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Catalog_Id`)
    REFERENCES `dbo`.`Catalogs` (`Id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

I was going to migrate data from SSMS to mysql. At last I got this error. How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Comment: You can be smart about this and make the hash of the textual value unique, not the actual value. It saves a ton of space.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [utf8mb4](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) so  4 bytes per character in needed in the worst case

Maximum key length is [767](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html) bytes that is *255* characters for **utf8** and *191* characters for **utf8mb4**

multiple options:

- use a different charset
- reduce the number of characters required
- build the uniqueness constraint on a shorter prefix, like this:

  (UNIQUE INDEX 'UQ_Discounts_CatalogCode' ('Catalog_Id' ASC, 'Code'(191) ASC))

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid that error by using the `Barracuda` file format and enabling the `innodb_large_prefix` variable.

See my blog post for full details: http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2014/07/29/using-innodb-large-prefix-to-avoid-error-1071/