# Mysql Error 1071 Specified Key value is too Long

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, web-hosting

I'm using my Web Application in *Godaddy Hosting Server*. **Php Version is 7.1** and **mysql Version is 5.6**

while i'm trying

```
ALTER TABLE aos_products_quotes   
    modify COLUMN discount varchar(255)  DEFAULT 'Percentage' NULL ,  
    modify COLUMN parent_type varchar(255)  NULL ,  
    modify COLUMN parent_id char(255)  NULL ;
```

these query in my domain sql server its shows

> MYSQL #1071 Error Specified Key value is too long

I think i need to use **mysql 5.7** or else need to set the **global prefix variable is 1**..But the Global setting need super privileges..At Godaddy side they told its impossible on Shared hosting..

I try my best about that issue so anyone guide me to solve that issue..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Comment: the attempted alterations have made an associated index too long i.e. one or more of those columns is involved in an index which would exceed a limitation if the alteration was implemented. look at the indexes (think "key" as in "primary key")

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to fix this:

1. You can try by changing the character set of columns so that they
   use less bytes in storage.
2. You can change / remove indexing of the table. May be you are using
   composite index whose limit is reached after this alteration.
3. Try less length of varchar() columns.

share the complete table structure to help you better.
Thanks