# yii2 recommended lengths in user table

Tags: database, mysqli, database-design, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

First of all I'm creating a yii2 advanced application, I'm NOT asking how to solve the 1071 error, Im asking how to twerk the migration script to better adjust it to my hosting database limitations

When uploading my site db from my localhost to a production server (shared hosting) i had the following error:

> ## 1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

So i had to rearrange my migration script with the following parameters:

```
$this->createTable('{{%user}}', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'username' => $this->string(60)->notNull()->unique(),
            'auth_key' => $this->string(32)->notNull(),
            'password_hash' => $this->string(70)->notNull(),
            'password_reset_token' => $this->string(70)->unique(),
            'email' => $this->string(60)->notNull()->unique(),

            'status' => $this->smallInteger()->notNull()->defaultValue(10),
            'created_at' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
            'updated_at' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
        ], $tableOptions);
```

But i had to guess the length of the auth_key, password_hash and password_reset_token fields

Are there recommended lengths for this fields and what are they?

Regards...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Comment: This is more of an index problem (I've marked the duplicated question). I've got these fields with 255 size and it's fine.

Comment: Its not a duplicate, its more like an explanation because i had already solved the mysql error, i just want to optimize the index values for a yii2 advanced application

Answer (score 0):

For hashed  field  depend of hashin algoritm for   SHA-1 (One used by mysql) value is always 160 bit long,
Depending of type of dat you use CHAR or BINARY then for  type with  4 bit per character athey  need 160/4 = 40 characters. But for  8 bit per character, you  need a 160/8 = 20 character long field.
If you use  the VARCHAR this require  an additional byte for the length of the fixed-length field. then

MD5 generates a 128-bit hash value. You can use CHAR(32) or BINARY(16) or VARCHAR(33)

SHA-1 generates a 160-bit hash value. You can use CHAR(40) or BINARY(20) or VARCHAR(41)

SHA-224 generates a 224-bit hash value. You can use CHAR(56) or BINARY(28) or VARCHAR(57)

SHA-256 generates a 256-bit hash value. You can use CHAR(64) or BINARY(32)  or or VARCHAR(65)

But normally is used SHA-1

Comment: but what about auth_key and password_reset_token fields?

Comment: depend  of   your need .. and the related  content you manage ..  if also for these field you using hash then these have the same lenght otherwise  depend of your data content length...