# Data Import in MySQL Workbench Fails with Error 1071: Specified key was too long

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to clone a MySql database to another server using MySQL Workbench.

I can use Data Export to export the file to a standalone file:

```
Dumping lti_dev (lti_board_pack, ...)
Running: mysqldump.exe --defaults-file="c:\users\kevin\appdata\local\temp\tmplg3ejq.cnf"  --user=xxx --host=111.2.33.44 --protocol=tcp --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE --routines --events "lti_dev"
09:35:07 Export of \\...\lti_dev8.sql has finished
```

But my Data Import fails due to a too long index:

```
Restoring \\...\lti_dev8.sql
Running: mysql.exe --defaults-file="c:\users\kevin\appdata\local\temp\tmp5zgghx.cnf"  --protocol=tcp --host=foo.bar.local --user=xxx --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments  < "\\...\\lti_dev8.sql"
ERROR 1071 (42000) at line 27: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

I've looked at [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes) but I don't see how that would apply to my problem.  I do have one index defined as varchar(512) and one as varchar(255) but both the import and export calls define the characters as UTF-8.

Moreover, I'm cloning a working production database.  So it's working, but I can't clone it to another server.

What's going on?

Comment: maybe a different MySQL version?. (like in the link you provided: "In MySQL version 5.7 and upwards this limit has been increased to 3072 bytes.")

Comment: @RolandStarke You may be onto something there.  My "from" is 5.7 and my "to" is 5.5.

Comment: @RolandStarke, yes that was the answer.  Put it in a post and I'll mark it as the answer.