# Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: php, mariadb

I have a migration file for my php project. I am getting this error

> Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max
>   key length is 767 bytes

I do understand this issue is due to varchar(512) and charset - UTF8 but how do I solve this? I cannot change in my migration script. Can I change some properties in my.ini of MySql?

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists usermaster (
  user_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  username varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id,username),
   KEY fk_um_idx (user_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_um_idx FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Can you upgrade to MySQL 5.7

Comment: Forgot to mention I have already updated MySQL to 10.1.31

Comment: Otherwise I had to change the charset of the table from `utf8mb4` to `utf8`

Comment: @Sinto I cannot change the script

Comment: ?? `MySQL to 10.1.31` I think you mean to say you are using `mariaDB` and not MySQL

Comment: Yes after upgrade it is MariaDB. I was getting the same error in MySQL 5.7. Therefore, I had to upgrade to check.

Comment: Latest MySQL 5.7.whatever can be used as max key length is 3000+ characters

Comment: Yes that is what I read in another post but it is still not working out.

Comment: Then you had better show us the schema definition for this table and its columns

Comment: Are you using Laravel, and if so, which version?

Comment: No I am not using Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

The following comment on a duplicate topic gives 2 possibilities if you insist on keeping the length of the username on 512: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41298282/5987517

I think the best solution in our case is to change your encoding from `UTF-8` to `latin1_general_ci`