# Unable to run simple migration: Specified key was too long error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I set up a new project with symfony and doctrine. I created a database using the following command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

Then I created an entity using the following command:

```
php bin/console make:entity
```

This was the code generated:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=24, nullable=true)
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $zip_code;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setPhone(?string $phone): self
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getZipCode(): ?int
    {
        return $this->zip_code;
    }

    public function setZipCode(int $zip_code): self
    {
        $this->zip_code = $zip_code;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

When I try to run the migration, I keep getting the following error:

```
php bin/console make:migration
```

And

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

This is extremely frustrating as I am using the command line generate code and a brand new project and have been trying to troubleshoot this for quite some time.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve.

Comment: What is your Db engine ?

Comment: I am not sure where I would decide that, I am using all the default configs that come with a new project.

Comment: So you use Mysql ? Can you try to add to change `@ORM\GeneratedValue()` to `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")`

Comment: Yes, I am using Mysql.

Comment: That didn't help, still getting the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814594/6663198 ?

Comment: @Flyzzx, that table doesn't exist, it never gets created. That post doesn't solve my problem. I also tried changing the character collation with no luck.

Comment: Wich version of Mysql do you use ? Maybe the mysql version that you have dismatch the version in your symfony configuration ?

Comment: Using version 5.6.38, where can I confirm the symfony configuration?

Comment: Inside the doctrine key in config.yml. if it not present, try to force the version like this :`# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        server_version: '5.6.38'` (Sorry for bad indentation)

Comment: There is no config.yml in symfony, you're likely thinking of laravel...

Comment: In your app directory.. I have many project in symfony and I confirm that they have a file named config.yml. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration

Comment: Again, there is no app directory in symfony, you're likely thinking of laravel...

Comment: If you use Symfony 4, there is a config directory directly. App directory is used in version <= 3

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I used `utf8mb4` as collation (more specifically `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`), which is now default for doctrine.

https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/1.6/config/packages/doctrine.yaml#L13

The strange thing is that I only had this problem with `unique` fields. I had to limit those to 191 characters, an answer I found here: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw the post you linked to. I changed all my lengths to 191 and ran the migration make and migration migration commands again, no luck. I also am using the exact sam collate that is specified in the doctrine.yaml file.

Comment: Just for a test, could you change that to simple utf8, generate and run migrations again?

Comment: thats what I did initially, no luck.

Comment: That is really weird, changing the collation to utf8_unicode_ci should have fixed it. I have no other ideas.

Comment: Could you post the generated migration? (I want to run it on my setup)

Comment: I removed all the migrations from src/Migrations, changed the charset to utf8 and ran make migration and the migrate command and it worked!