# How to import a huge dump which returns "Index column size too large" error?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `db_dump.sql` file which has a huge size, about 1GB. I'm importing it this way:

```
mysql -u root -p dbname < path/to/db_dump.sql
```

It throws the following error after a short time while importing:

> ERROR 1709 (HY000) at line 2419: Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.

How can I fix the problem?

---

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1814532/2805376) post but I don't know how should I modify that huge dump. My computer will be freazed when I'm opening that huge dump using a editor and also I don't know how should I find the issue in thousand lines of data.

Comment: For now, dump the index part and just import, then 'try' to recreate the index (Though it might not work as it exceeds the size).  It's importing or trying to create?

Comment: It is importing an already-exported-dump.

Comment: I already got this issue, with a 2GB dump file.  The error was my source db was corrupted.  I fix my source, dump again and it solve my issue.

Comment: I frequently use ultraedit to edit big file, like 2GB.  It is slow but doesn't hang because it use chunk of file.  https://www.ultraedit.com/

Comment: How big is the file?  it might be what Daniel Blais said.  Because it's from an export, you should not have the Index issue.