# Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 MariaDB 10.1

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mariadb

Ive been searching to try and find out why I am getting the following error when trying to copy a database to my production server.

```
Specified key was too long; max key length is 767
```

I export from my dev box and import on the server running

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.25-MariaDB
```

Comment: Already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes

Comment: Thanks Guys, so looks like i need to move to MariaDB 10.2 or later?

Comment: @GlenRobson - that's one of 5 solutions.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52749571/1766831