# MySql phpMyAdmin, can't set unique

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table (as seen below), this is default from Laravel. However when i try and make the `email` column unique, i receive the following error:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD UNIQUE(`email`);

MySQL said: Documentation
#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

**Table as seen in phpMyAdmin**

[image: View of table]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Comment: Like the error says a unique constraint can only be a max of 767 bytes. `utf8mb4` is up to 4 bytes per character, so 255 characters would be 1020 bytes.

Comment: So changing it to utf8_bin worked

Answer (score -4):

Try this

ALTER IGNORE TABLE `users` ADD UNIQUE(`email`);

Comment: Instead of just saying “try this”, could you explain why that would solve the problem?