# Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

db version: `10.1.35-MariaDB`

charset: `utf8`

I was getting error: `Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes` so I changed column length to `255`. But i need to allow `varchar(1000)` in column, so when I enter large data in db column it says: `Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column`

How can I allow large data?

Comment: 'But i need to allow varchar(1000) in column,' - then it cannot be a key and you should read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes

Comment: See my list of [_5 workarounds for 767_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes) -- each has a caveat, so you have to decide which you can live with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @P.Salmon.

The column length restriction is only for keys. All other columns can have any length.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the column length max, then it will work

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype(MAX);
```

Comment: mysql does not have datatype(MAX) construct.