# mysql to mariadb restoring backup

Tags: mysql, collation

My mysql database dump is fine but when I go to restore it on a new server which uses mariadb it will only partially restore and then throw an error;

#1071 - Specified key was too long: max key length is 767 bytes

I have found that when I'm installing with a program it works when I use Force UTF-8 collation on database" and "Force UTF-8 collation on tables"  but I don't know how to do that when I just have the raw sql file - help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed can replacing `utf8mb4` by `utf8` in the raw sql dump.

Other solutions can be found here: [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Comment: Worked a treat.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This problem existed before the limit was raised in 5.7.7 (MariaDB 10.2.2?).

If you are hitting the limit because of trying to use `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  Then do one of the following (each has a drawback) to avoid the error:

- Upgrade to 5.7.7 (or later) for a 3072 byte limit;
- Change 255 to 191 on the `VARCHAR` -- you lose any values longer than 191 characters (unlikely?);
- `ALTER .. CONVERT TO utf8` -- you lose Emoji and some of Chinese;
- Use a "prefix" index -- you lose some of the performance benefits.
- Or... Stay with 5.6/5.5/10.1 but perform 4 steps to raise the limit to 3072 bytes:

  ```
  SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
  SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=1;
  SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix=1;
  logout & login (to get the global values);
  ALTER TABLE tbl ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;  -- (or COMPRESSED)
  ```