# MySQL 5.7: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Tags: mysql

I maintain an application we use at work. Last week I updated my homestead that I use to run the application local. For some reason I now get an error when some queries run. The query used to work but it now gives the following error:
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes`.

The query that produces the error is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS surveyswitch_data (
    `survey_from` INT( 11)NOT NULL ,
    `survey_to` INT( 11)NOT NULL ,
    `name` VARCHAR( 255)NOT NULL ,
    `value` VARCHAR( 255)NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`survey_from` ,`survey_to` ,`name`) 
) ENGINE=MYISAM;
```

The only thing that has changed is that I updated homestead, that includes apache and mysql. The mysql version on homestead is 5.7.28 now. On our server, where the query still works, we have mysql 5.7.27.

I already tried to change to innodb_large_prefix on. That didn't help. What setting should I change to make it work again?

Comment: Probably your charset has changed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Comment: Kudos for tuning innodb with myisam tables.

Comment: @NicoHaase But then I have to change the query. Why is the query working on our mysql 5.7.27 server but not on 5.7.28? Can I fix it without changing the query.

Comment: Have you tried to check whether all configuration matches? What about the charset - you haven't specified it explicitly in your query

Comment: @NicoHaase The charset is utf8mb4 for the database. I will check the configuration.

Comment: Well, if the charset is mb4-based, then the error message is pretty obvious to read: using mb4, the size of `value` is already 1020 bytes which is more than 1000 bytes. And according to the documentation, `innodb_large_prefix`only works for specific row formats and is, immediately after being introduced, already deprecated

Comment: My bad, I thought the same character set was used on the production server. Seems it was just utf8 and not utf8mb4. Changed my Homestead to utf8 and now it works. Thanks a lot for pointing it out!