# Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes using knex

Tags: mysql, knex.js

I've created the following transaction:

```
exports.up = async (knex, Promise) => (await knex.schema.hasTable('settings'))
    ? null
    : knex.schema.createTable('settings', function (table) {
        table.increments('id')
        table.string('name').notNullable().unique()
        table.string('value').notNullable()

        table.primary('name')
    }).then(() => {
        return knex('settings').insert([
            { name: 'sandbox', value: 'off'},
            { name: 'promo', value: 'off'}
        ]);
    });

exports.down = async (knex, Promise) => (await knex.schema.hasTable('settings'))
    ? knex.schema.dropTable('settings')
    : null
```

essentially I'm trying to create a `settings` table which define two primary keys, an `id` and a `name`. The problem is that I get this error:

> migration failed with error: alter table `settings` add unique `settings_name_unique`(`name`) - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

how can I fix?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes` is coming from MySQL and is [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes). The default length of a `string` in knex is 255. With four byte utf8mb4 characters this is 1,020 bytes. Yes, this is very annoying.

You can fix this by [using the dynamic row format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-row-format.html#innodb-row-format-dynamic). This is the default for new tables since 5.7.9, so you might also look into upgrading MySQL.

Or you can set a lower max length for the string. You can do this by passing a length into [`string`](https://knexjs.org/#Schema-string). With four byte characters that's 767 / 4 = 191 characters.

```
table.string('name', 191).notNullable().unique()
```